# Check if columns in SQL table have the same values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table like below

[image]

I want to return the rows whose `col_1`, `col_2`, and `col_3` values are not the same.
In the example above, it should return the 2nd and 3rd row (with key `ghj-ikl` and `tgl-pkl`). All 3 columns have to have the same values.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: `... where (col_1 <> col_2) or (col_1 <> col_3)`.

Comment: So what have you tried and what specific issue are you having?

Comment: Your desired result doesn't seem to match your stated requirement.  In row 3, col_2 = col_3, which you say should be excluded.  Maybe a typo in your sample data?

Comment: @Andrew All 3 columns need to have the same values, so although col_2 = col_3, it doesn't pass the requirement because col_1 != col_2

Comment: Is it exactly 3 columns or are you looking for a solution for arbitrary number of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select * from your_table 
where (
  select count(distinct el) > 1
  from unnest([col_1, col_2, col_3]) el
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution for any arbitrary number of columns - so you don't need to explicitly list them

```
select * from your_table t
where (
    select count(distinct el) > 1
    from unnest(split(trim(format('%t', (select as struct * except(key) from unnest([t]))), '()'), ', ')) el
  )
```

if apple data in your question - output is

[image]